# empty POST body to JSON using ObjectMapper

Tags: java, json, servlets, jackson, objectmapper

i'm trying to read the POST payload using object mapper

```
ServletInputStream in = null;
    try {
        in = request.getInputStream();
        originalInputStreamMap = mapper.readValue(in,
                new TypeReference<Map<String, String>>() {
                });
        somemap.putAll(somattr);
    } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (in != null) {
            in.close();
        }
    }
```

but if the POST request body is empty

> mapper.readValue

will throw an error. my use case is that if there is no request body, i need to set the hashmap to the request body(**somemap**).

Comment: Please show the error stack trace.